# C - One-time pad encryption via a bit-by-bit process using StdIn and StdOut

Tags: c, file, encryption, stdin, xor

I would like to find out how may I use a key file for XOR encryption as opposed to only using a single number for k. What I am finding challenging with this problem is:

1. How would we be able to encrypt the input file with the key file on a byte by byte basis?
2. How would we check that the key is longer than the message?
3. Would we be able to recover the original message using the same XOR operation?

My code are included below:

```
    while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF) { //problem lies here

        k = fgetc(k); // <- ERROR:  incompatible integer to pointer conversion assigning to 'FILE *

        fputc(c ^ k, out);
    }
```

Comment: 1. Use a loop. 2. Why does it matter, just go back to the beginning of the key. 3. Yes, XOR is its own inverse.

Comment: You can always just wrap the XOR key if the plaintext file is longer than the key.

Comment: `k = fgetc(k);`. You're using the same variable for the file and the value you read from it.

Comment: Specifically, you'll want a `int d;` which you can read into. `d = fgetc(k);`

Comment: 2. If you read `EOF` from the key file before reading `EOF` from the input file, then the key file was too short.

Answer (score 1):

When you get to the end of the key file, rewind back to the beginning.

You also need to use a different variable for the character you read from the key file, instead of reusing `k`.

```
while ((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF) {
    int kc = fgetc(k);
    if (kc == EOF) {
        rewind(k);
        kc = fgetc(k);
    }
    fputc(c ^ kc, out);
}
```

This same technique will work for decrypting, since XOR is symmetric. `(c ^ kc) ^ kc == c`